# dpkg: error processing package php8.1-common

Tags: apt, 20.04, dpkg, php, awk

I know that my error is a very classic one, and I encountered it without doing it on purpose and i need to resolve the problem because i'm working with php.

```
❯ php
zsh: command not found: php
```

and:

```
❯ sudo apt-get install php
```

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
php is already the newest version (2:8.1+92+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
7 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up php8.1-common (8.1.7-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
/usr/bin/ucf: line 569: awk: command not found
dpkg: error processing package php8.1-common (--configure):
 installed php8.1-common package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php8.1:
 php8.1 depends on php8.1-common; however:
  Package php8.1-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php8.1 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php8.1-cli:
 php8.1-cli depends on php8.1-common (= 8.1.7-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1); however:
  Package php8.1-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php8.1-cli (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php8.1-readline:
 php8.1-readline depends on php8.1-common (= 8.1.7-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1); however:
  Package php8.1-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php8.1-readline (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libapache2-mod-php8.1:
 libapache2-mod-php8.1 depends on php8.1-cli; however:
  Package phpNo apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                           No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                         No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                           No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                             No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                           8.1-cli is not configured yet.
 libapache2-mod-php8.1 depends on php8.1-common (= 8.1.7-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1); however:
  Package php8.1-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libapache2-mod-php8.1 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php8.1-opcache:
 php8.1-opcache depends on php8.1-common (= 8.1.7-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1); however:
  Package php8.1-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php8.1-opcache (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php:
 php depends on php8.1; however:
  Package php8.1 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 php8.1-common
 php8.1
 php8.1-cli
 php8.1-readline
 libapache2-mod-php8.1
 php8.1-opcache
 php
```

and :

```
❯ sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

```
Setting up php8.1-common (8.1.7-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
/usr/bin/ucf: line 569: awk: command not found
dpkg: error processing package php8.1-common (--configure):
 installed php8.1-common package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php8.1:
 php8.1 depends on php8.1-common; however:
  Package php8.1-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php8.1 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php8.1-cli:
 php8.1-cli depends on php8.1-common (= 8.1.7-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1); however:
  Package php8.1-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php8.1-cli (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php8.1-readline:
 php8.1-readline depends on php8.1-common (= 8.1.7-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1); however:
  Package php8.1-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php8.1-readline (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libapache2-mod-php8.1:
 libapache2-mod-php8.1 depends on php8.1-cli; however:
  Package php8.1-cli is not configured yet.
 libapache2-mod-php8.1 depends on php8.1-common (= 8.1.7-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1); however:
  Package php8.1-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libapache2-mod-php8.1 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php8.1-opcache:
 php8.1-opcache depends on php8.1-common (= 8.1.7-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1); however:
  Package php8.1-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php8.1-opcache (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php:
 php depends on php8.1; however:
  Package php8.1 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 php8.1-common
 php8.1
 php8.1-cli
 php8.1-readline
 libapache2-mod-php8.1
 php8.1-opcache
 php
```

I don't know what to do exactly, i did apt purge for php and re install it, but the problem persist.
What can i do to resolve that ?
Don't bother with the awk error,
Thank you guys :')

Comment: `/usr/bin/ucf: line 569: awk: command not found` is very strange. A Linux system without `awk`?

Comment: Why did you write "don't bother with the awk error"? Don't you think it could be the problem and it should be installed? On which system are you working? ```awk``` should be already installed per default

Comment: it seems like *the problem is* the awk error. You most probably won't be able to fix this until you get `awk` working.

Comment: Because i encountered this error 1 month ago, and i was working with my computer and my php normally without any problem, and i don't think that's the real issue.

Comment: *it's telling you* that that's the issue. Why don't you believe it?

Comment: You really need to install it, otherwise the package can't be configured. Perhpas it wasn't needed for other versions...

Comment: Let's just hope you don't need `awk` to install `awk`. That's how basic it is.

Comment: each time i open up terminal i get this error before the prompt line : "nvm_version_greater:1: too many levels of symbolic links: awk
nvm_die_on_prefix:33: too many levels of symbolic links: awk
" and everything was fine, that's why i didn't get any doubt on that package.

Comment: ``` ❯ where awk 
awk not found
❯ awk
zsh: too many levels of symbolic links: awk``` is it normal ?

Comment: No it's not normal. Install awk and this problem is probably solved. But a system without awk may have other problems...

Comment: ``` ❯ sudo apt-get install awk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package awk is a virtual package provided by:
  original-awk 2012-12-20-6
  mawk:i386 1.3.4.20200120-2
  gawk:i386 1:5.0.1+dfsg-1
  mawk 1.3.4.20200120-2
  gawk 1:5.0.1+dfsg-1
You should explicitly select one to install.

E: Package 'awk' has no installation candidate``` <br/> Well, i don't know which one should i get ...

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 comes with `gawk 1:5.1.0-1build3` and `mawk 1.3.4.20200120-3` installed by default. Can you type `which awk` and paste output? also try installing both `gawk` and `mawk`

Comment: I Actually installed original-awk (cause it appears first), and then ran dpkg configure -a, and everything it's fine now, thank you so much guys you saved my life :)

Comment: It sounds like your `awk` was symlinked to itself somehow, I guess installing a new one fixed the symlink issues

Comment: @Esther You might want to post that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this line from the error messages:
`/usr/bin/ucf: line 569: awk: command not found`. This means that your PC needed `awk`, a text processing tool, in order to configure the PHP packages, but couldn't find it installed.

This is very strange, because [`awk`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) is a *very* basic system package that comes installed by default on all Linux systems. Your system very much relies on it in order to function properly.

From your comment about the error `too many levels of symbolic links`, it sounds like your `awk` was somehow [symlinked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) to itself (or possibly to another symlink, which in turn linked to the first), which resulted in your system following the same link over and over infinitely and (obviously) not being able to find the actual program. This can happen if you ran some command by mistake, or possibly if you deleted `awk` by mistake.

The easiest solution would be to re-install `awk` using `apt`. Re-installing packages can often fix broken symlinks, because part of the install process is often creating all the necessary symbolic links for the system to recognize a package. Ubuntu 22.04 comes with the `gawk` and `mawk` packages by default, both of which provide the `awk` utility. Installing either of these, or some other version of `awk` such as `awk-original`, using `apt` can fix the issue. If the one you chose is indeed already installed, add the `--reinstall` flag to force `apt` to install it anyways (since that should fix broken symlinks). For example, use `apt install --reinstall gawk`.